# How do you access the 'userLabel' field of interface builder components in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, interface-builder

I am integrating an iOS project with an automated testing package that uses the Accessibility Identifier property of UI Elements to run actions and tests on them.  I would like to fill in these fields at runtime using the best identifiers possible and the titles that have been entered for elements in interface builder are great candidates for use in this project.
[image]

I know that there are many other legitimate names that could be used for this particular application but those don't pertain to my question.

I don't see any apple documentation of these names but I see that they can be found in the xib xml as below:
[image]

Is there an exposed way to access the "userLabel" property for UI Elements in apple's UIKit (or via any other manner)?

Comment: this text actually is not even user-facing, as I understand, the sting that you are going to see in the app is @"Label Text!", and it's a property .text of the UILabel, which storyboard id is "7cp-TB-Qab"

Comment: The username isn't in the compiled nib.

Answer (score 4):

@Willeke is right, the `userLabel` isn't compiled into the nib.